# Taking backups from Galera cluster slave

Tags: percona, galera

We have a 3 node Percona Xtradb cluster and two async slaves hanging off the cluster. Is it possible to take backups from the slave using Xtrabackup and use that backup to restore on the cluster node.

Answer (score 0):

To re-seed a cluster node Percona Xtradb Cluster needs specific information which is not available from an asynchronous slave. So no, you wouldn't be able to use the async slave backup to restore on the cluster node.

However, as long as the asynchronous slave remains consistent with the Percona Xtradb Cluster node it should be sufficient for data backup.

Any asynchronous slave which provides for data backup in this way ideally should be subject to regular consistency verification.

Comment: But is it enough to restore the data, exclusive of the Galera-specific configuration?  If not, what is missing?

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the answer to incorporate your point.